# Unable to create or update file with the client-side encryption via Google Drive API

Tags: rest, encryption, google-drive-api

I'm working on the utility for the replication of Google Drive items. I use Google Drive API endpoints for fetching file content and creating and updating it. I see no problems with the regular files. I can also get the content of the files with client-side encryption via API. However, creating and updating the drive file using that information fails. I perform all operations on behalf of the user who owns the target Google Drive.

I use [Google Drive API v3 vesion](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3).

**Case #1. Encrypted files creation:**

1. Create the file with the client-side encryption in the user's Google Drive.
2. Get the content and properties of the file using [files.get Drive API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get) as described in the [Download & export files article](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads).
3. Remove the file from Google Drive.
4. Call the [files.create Drive API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create) to create the file:

> /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true

**Expected result:** The file with the client-side encryption to Google Drive is successfully created in the target Google Drive.

**Actual result:** The creation of the file fails. The [files.create Drive API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create) returns the following reply:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Error",
        "errors": [{
                "message": "Internal Error",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "internalError"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Case #2. Encrypted files update:**

1. Create the file with the client-side encryption in the user's Google Drive.
2. Get the content and properties of the file using [files.get Drive API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get) as described in the [Download & export files article](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads).
3. Update the file content or rename it in Google Drive.
4. Call the [files.update Drive API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update) to update the file:

> /upload/drive/v3/files/1jgqU0S7hunpCYwXiJGT7kjkxUaJ5aJLq?uploadType=media&supportsAllDrives=true

**Expected result:** The file with the client-side encryption to Google Drive is reverted to the previous state.

**Actual result:** The file is not updated. Response form the [files.update Drive API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update) is the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
        "errors": [{
                "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Additinal information:**
I use only one user for verification of the cases provided here. This user created files with client-side encryption in his Google Drive folder. I logged in with this user while doing API requests.

Also, I noticed unusual mime type for the encryped files after getting information about them. For example, for encrypted presentation it's

> application/vnd.google-gsuite.encrypted; content="application/vnd.google-gsuite.presentation-blob"

For encrypted spreadsheet file:

> application/vnd.google-gsuite.encrypted; content="application/vnd.google-gsuite.spreadsheet-blob"

Is this a known issue? Are there any limitations to working with the files with the client-side encryption using Google Drive API?

Comment: The user you are logged in with needs access to the file or you are going to get the error "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."   make sure the user you are logging in with has permissions needed to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I use only one user for verification of the cases provided here. This user created files with client-side encryption in his Google Drive folder. I logged in with this user while doing API requests.

Comment: check the permissions on the file the user doesn't have access

Comment: Permissions on the files with the client-side encryption and those without encryption are the same in the scope of user's drive.